# Send JSON as POST to Django using Ajax

Tags: json, django

I'm looking to send some JSON POST data to a URL in Django which enforces CSRF protection. My Ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/change_ref/'+hash+"/",

        data: {"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}", "new_ref": newref},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('#changeref').modal('hide');
            alert('Success!');
        },
        failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert('Failure! ' +errMsg);
        }
    });
```

My idea is to then parse the JSON on the backend. However, when I examine the POST data passed to the server, it is empty (as seen by CSRF middleware):

[image]

This happens also when I wrap the JSON data with `JSON.stringify()`. The only way I have POST requests working so far is with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` Mimetype, but this is undesirable.

My settings.py is pretty vanilla. Are there any extra steps needed in order to make JSON POSTs in Django, or is there something blatantly wrong with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF token should be in HTTP header, so also ContentType

```
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending form-encoded data, so `request.POST` is not used. Get it from `request.body` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with fetching the POST data for form validation on the backend